# Ruby: Building a token generator on top of a string

Tags: regex, ruby, string

I would like to create a class which can be instantiated on a String and a Regex (which describes how to tokenize a string), and provides a method `next_token`, which returns the respectively next part of the string matching the regex, in the way that `String#scan` is working. For instance, if I do a

```
t = Tokenizer.new('abcdefgh', /.../)
a = t.next_token
b = t.next_token
c = t.next_token
```

should set `a` to `'abc'` and `b` to `'def'` and `c` to `nil`. This is an obvious and simple solution:

```
class Tokenizer
  def initialize(str, reg)
     @tokenized_str = str.scan(reg)
     @next_ind = 0
  end
  def next_token
     @tokenized_str[@next_ind].tap { @next_ind += 1 }
  end
end
```

This solution requires that the whole string is split apart into an array in the constructor. I would like to implement a "lazy" approach, where the next token is calculated only when the call to `next_token` is issued. Can someone suggest how to do it? Actually, `String#scan` must have such a generator already built in, because we can call it with a block, but I don't see how to make use of it in my case.

I wonder whether this is a good way to use a `Fiber`, because what I'm doing here smells like co-routines, but perhaps there is an easier solution for this kind of problem. Performance will also be an issue, because my application will make heavy use of the `Tokenizer` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are nearly there. You need *an enumerator instance*.

```rb
class Tokenizer
  def initialize(str, reg)
    #             THIS   ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
    @tokenized_str = str.enum_for(:scan, reg)
  end
  def next_token
   @tokenized_str.next
  end
end
```

Beware that [`Enumerator#next`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) raises `StopIteration` if there is nothing left to iterate, so you probably want to handle it somehow.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`StringScanner#scan_until`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html#method-i-scan_until) and then remove the part matching the pattern with `String#split` or `String#gsub`:

```
ss = StringScanner.new('a-b-c-d-e-f-g')
#=> #<StringScanner 0/13 @ "a-b-c...">
while s = ss.scan_until(/-/)
   puts s.gsub(/-/, '') # or s.split(/-/)
end  
#a
#b
#c
#d
#e
#f
#=> nil
```

Comment: I was not even aware that `StringScanner` existed! Unfortunately I can accept only one answer as correct, and for my application, the solution proposed by Aleksei looks a tiny bit more natural for my application.

Comment: I didn't know about it until today :-)

Comment: I knew about `ScreenScanner` before today, but only vaguely. I think you want `scan_until` or `skip_until`, and while that returns a non-`nil` value, `matched` is to follow, which returns the match of the pattern. Both `scan_until` and `skip_until` attempt to match the pattern and advance the *scan pointer* to the end of the match. If successful, `scan_until` returns a string comprised of the substring beginning just after the previous position of the scan pointer and ending at the end of the match; `skip_until` returns the size of that the string...

Comment: ...The important thing is that a truthy value is returned by both methods. Here is an example taken from my answer. `str = 'bacdefaghi'; reg =  /(?<=a)../; ss = StringScanner.new str
 #=> #<StringScanner 0/10 @ "bacde...">; while ss.scan_until reg; puts ss.matched; end`, which displays `"cd"` and `"gh"` on separate lines, and returns `nil` (or replace `scan_until` with `skip_until`).

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland :). I prefer assigning `scan_until` result than using internal state in `matched`, it's personal though. OTH `StringScanner` is all about using internal state, so I shouldn't mind

Comment: ...but with my example and your code, `"ba"` and `"efa"` are displayed (but I think you could replace `s.gsub(reg,'')` with `s[reg]`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland it seems that I assumed that regex is a separator (as in `split`) and you, that it's the content (like in `scan`). I've checked that OP wanted the `scan` behaviour,

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub).

```
class Tokenizer
  def initialize(str, reg)
    @token_enum = str.gsub(reg)
  end

  def next_token
   @token_enum.next
  end
end
```

```
t = Tokenizer.new('bacdefaghi', /(?<=a)../)
  #=> #<Tokenizer:0x00005af867bfc6f0 @tokenized_str=
  #     #<Enumerator: "bacdefaghi":gsub(/(?<=a)../)>> 

t.next_token  #=> "cd" 
t.next_token  #=> "gh" 
t.next_token  #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
```